# If I'm sorting objects using compare, how do I tell it to not sort if one of the objects is nil?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sorting

Say I have the following block of code:

```
[allKeys sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
    NSDictionary *firstArticle = [articles objectForKey:(NSString *)obj1];
    NSNumber *firstSortID = [firstArticle objectForKey:@"sort_id"];

    NSDictionary *secondArticle = [articles objectForKey:(NSString *)obj2];
    NSNumber *secondSortID = [secondArticle objectForKey:@"sort_id"];

    if (firstSortID == nil || secondSortID == nil) {
        return nil;
    }
    else {
        return [secondSortID compare:firstSortID];
    }
}];
```

I get the warning:

> Incompatible pointer to integer conversion returning 'void *' from a
>   function with result type 'NSComparisonResult' (aka 'enum
>   NSComparisonResult')

But basically, if one of them is nil, it crashes because the comparison doesn't make sense. How do I tell it that if it's nil, don't bother, just stop.

Comment: The warning: you are returning nil instead of a NSComparisonResult ...

Comment: What is holding the sorted objects? None of the usual NS data structures stores nils.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to decide how you want `nil` values to be sorted. Most likely they should go at the end of the list. You want something like this:

```
if (firstSortID) {
    if (secondSortID) {
        // Both set, compare
        NSComparisonResult result = [firstSortID compare:secondSortID];
        if (result == NSOrderedSame) {
            // optionally do another comparison on a secondary value
            // result = ...
        }
        return result;
    } else {
        // Have 1st but not 2nd
        return NSOrderedAscending;
    }
} else {
    if (secondSortID) {
       // Have 2nd but not 1st
       return NSOrderedDescending;
    } else {
       // Both nil, treat as the same
       // Another option here is to look at another value in the dictionary to be used as a secondary sort
       return NSOrderedSame;
    }
}
```

Comment: Easiest solution, but the order of the objets w/nil attributes will be unstable.

Comment: That is solved if a secondary value is used as stated in the code comment when both values are `nil`.

Comment: I can't brain well enough to think through whether that is going to produce a guaranteed stable sort regardless of object state.  I.e. will switching sort keys only in the `nil,nil` context work?

Comment: Actually, you also need the secondary (or even higher) sort if both values are not `nil` and the result of `compare:` returns `NSOrderedSame`. I'll update my answer with that detail.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot prematurely terminate the sort using `sortUsingComparator:`. So you must sort the `nil` values - just decide whether `nil` should be the least or greatest value and return `NSOrderedDescending`, `NSOrderedAscending` or `NSOrderedSame` as appropriate.

If you need to know whether you hit a `nil` then set a flag in your block which you can test afterwards. The flag needs to be declared with the `__block` qualifier so it can be modified within your block, e.g.:

```
__block BOOL nilFound = NO;
[allKeys sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2)
{
   NSDictionary *firstArticle = [articles objectForKey:(NSString *)obj1];
   NSNumber *firstSortID = [firstArticle objectForKey:@"sort_id"];

   NSDictionary *secondArticle = [articles objectForKey:(NSString *)obj2];
   NSNumber *secondSortID = [secondArticle objectForKey:@"sort_id"];

   // set flag - could alternatively be set during comparison logic below
   if (firstSortID == nil || secondSortID == nil)
      nilFound = YES;

   // actual comparison, allowing for nil values
   ...
}];

// was a nil found?
if (nilFound) ...
```

**Addendum**

Others have raised the issue of a stable sort, you should be able to address this by using the original keys, e.g.:

```
if (firstSortID == nil)
{
   if (secondSortID == nil)
   {
      // both nil - use original keys as secondary sort, obj1 & obj2 are strings
      return [obj1 compare:obj2];
   }
   else
      return NSSortAscending;
}
else
   return secondSortID == nil ? NSSortDescending : [secondSortID compare:firstSortID];
```

(You can switch the `NSSortAscending` & `NSSortDescending` to have the `nil` values grouped at the other end.)

Comment: You shouldn't need to have the `== nil` check if the type can be of id. `if (!firstSortID || !secondSortID)` is good enough.

Comment: @OliverAtkinson - Any object reference (or C pointer *et al.*) can be tested as you suggest. The choice is largely a matter of style.